# How would you "redirect" to a login form using Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm not sure what the "next.js" way would be in this case.

What I'm trying to accomplish: read a cookie, see if there is a "JWT" cookie, and either display a login form or redirect to a page with a login form.

What would be the Next.js way of doing this? I would prefer to redirect to a page that has a login form on it, or is this not possible?

I wasn't able to find any information on dynamic redirects for next.js

Answer (score 1):

I already posted the answer yesterday to your other question

```
ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/login" });
```

see the full post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421136/4632620

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to programmatically redirect or change the URL in Nextjs, you use the router: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush